# What does "Share Song" in Apple Music?

Tags: music, sharing, apple-music, music.app

I clicked `Share Song`, but didn't receive any feedback (what Apple Music did).

Is there some kind of social network? Do I have a profile? Who sees the shared songs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting a pop-up like the below screenshot:
[image]

Then you'd be able to share via any app you like. It will create a link to the song you've chosen to share.

Sources:
[iOSHacker](http://ioshacker.com/how-to/quickly-share-your-favorite-apple-music-songs-with-friends-tip)